# Problems when booting Ubuntu 12.04 on separate hard drive

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, hard-drive, uefi

I just got Ubuntu 12.04 (also have it on my Chromebook), and I installed it on my seperate hard drive. Whenever I try to boot my computer up, I get Windows Boot Manager, as expected. But then there's a problem. When I click "Ubuntu", this error message pops up:

```
File: \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr

Status: 0xc000007b
```

I have seen other questions like this, but this is on my *separate* hard drive. It might be that I have a UEFI motherboard. I checked for a "legacy boot" option, but can't find it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it a WUBI install?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to figure out how to remove the WUBI to make it GRUB.

Comment: I don't think WUBI will work correctly on an external drive. Windows is complaining about WUBI not being found where it was originally installed, this is probably due to the fact that it is on a separate hard drive.

Comment: Check out https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateWubi.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go check it out and see if it works.

Edit: Well, that doesn't really work for me because Ubuntu won't even start up... and I don't want to override my existing Windows installation.

Comment: Do you have any important files on WUBI? I suggest taking them off and putting them into Windows, see (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_can_I_access_the_Wubi_files_from_Windows.3F), and then installing Ubuntu onto the external hard drive with a Live USB or Live DVD.

Comment: Just looked at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide and it says it won't work on Systems with UEFI firmware. I think that is causing your error. I suggest doing a real install on the external drive.

Comment: Eh, I'll just boot it alongside my Windows drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Wubi isn't compatible with my mainboard. I tried the graphical install from the LiveUSB... with UEFI, which was stupid because I couldn't see the GUI... then I used Legacy boot. It works! Thanks for all of your help guys :)

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation:**

the error message you got means you tried to install Ubuntu inside Windows (via the Wubi installer).
The problem is that Wubi is not compatible with GPT (preinstalled Windows8 and some Win7 are on GPT disks).

**Solution:**

Install Ubuntu the standard way, on its own partitions, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall